# Xcode does not simply run tests - no scheme and/or test plan

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild

## Objective

Running simple unit-test for an iOS app.

### Setup

- Xcode (Version 14.1)

Sample Test:

```swift
import XCTest
@testable import SDKTestAppSwift

class SDKTestAppSwiftTests: XCTestCase {

    func testExample() throws {
        print("Test: testExample")
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        let base = "asdfghjkl123"

        XCTAssert(base == "asdfghjkl123")
    }

}
```

Next to the ..

> func testExample() throws {

.. Xcode provides a nice little '**start single test**'-button.

I used to klick it to start the test, locally (Xcode IDE on mac).

This used to work properly.

### Problem

Klicking the '**start single test**'-button, an overlay appears:

[image: Xcode warning overlay - information below]

For the sake of this question to be machine-readable:

> **There is no scheme and/or test plan that contains every test you are trying to run.**
> Create a new scheme and/or test plan containing the tests you want to run.

To close the overlay an 'OK'-Button is delivered only.

### Misleading solution (?!)

Just before there was no such scheme needed.
I wonder why would that changes 'suddenly'.

From my point ov view Scheme/Testplans are executed 'on startup' of the device-emulator (or likewise), which is **not my objective** in the first place.

However - creating a TestPlan via:

> File > New > File... > TestPlan

Adding the **SDKTestAppSwiftTests**-class using the **+**-Button.

... no success ... :-/

### Several other attempts

It seems my system is not the only one facing likewise issues.

1. **Problems with naming of test plans**

- [xcodebuild: Tests cannot be run because the test plan “Scheme” could not be read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73237456/xcodebuild-tests-cannot-be-run-because-the-test-plan-scheme-could-not-be-read)

> No matter if there is a 'test-plan' and whatever name I assigned it - this is no solution.

2. **Default test plan**

- https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133495

> I seriously do not know how to create a 'default test plan' if it was not the way decribed before.

3. **Quit Xcode and delete 'old configurations'**

- [Xcode: No Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21755799/xcode-no-scheme)
- [xcodebuild says does not contain scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14368938/xcodebuild-says-does-not-contain-scheme)

> Something about files with old configurations which have to be deleted

In this case I am not sure which file and where to find it exactly.

## Conclusion

Even though one of the obove may help you, for me the issue is not solved, yet.

## Anyways

Thanks for reading & sharing - any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 6):

For me I fixed this through my scheme → Edit Scheme → Test → Plus Sign (Add Test Target) and then adding my unit test target.

Answer (score 1):

There is another solution ...

### First - Manage Schemes

[image: Navigate to 'manage schemes']

[image: Edit schemes]

### Second - Create new Scheme

[image: Navigate to 'create new scheme']

[image: Create new scheme]

### Third -> Celebrate, it's done .. :)